# Subsequence produced as a conclusion from bolzano weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis

In the statement of the Bolzano weierstrass theorem, it says every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence.

So does that mean that if $x_n \in [a,b]$, then we could construct a subsequence $x_{n_{k}} \to \alpha : \forall \alpha \in [a,b]$?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OCufT-m-wWNHqxpZqbYaZGKzmicmvtTl

Link to the proof where this is considered.

Comment: Yes, but note that in the conclusion you don't get to choose the $\alpha$.

Comment: Does that mean you cannot choose which $\alpha$ it converges to right?

Comment: Yes, "don't get to choose" = "cannot choose".

Comment: My professor used the assumption that you can select $\alpha$ to prove a theorem.

Comment: What exactly did they do?

Comment: How did they go about the proof? I don't believe this proof should require you to be able to select *any* such $\alpha$.

Comment: drive.google.com/open?id=1OCufT-m-wWNHqxpZqbYaZGKzmicmvtTl link to the proof

Answer (score 1):

The statement of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem tells us that if $x_n\in [a,b]$, then there exists an element $\alpha \in [a,b]$ such that there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}\to \alpha$.

Strictly speaking, we don't necessarily know that we could construct such a subsequence. This is the difference between constructive and nonconstructive mathematics. As in, given some sequence, there's not necessarily an algorithm or computer program you could write that could infer a suitable value of $\alpha$ and a corresponding subsequence. But we do know (from the axiom of choice) that such a sequence must exist, even if we don't know a way of constructing it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me make it clear once and for all.
If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $[a,b]$,then $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence,so by bolzano weierstrass theorem,we can claim that there exists a subsequence $(x_{r_n})$ which is convergent,say to $\alpha$,Now $[a,b]$ is a closed set,So any convergent sequence in this set converges to a point in that set,so $\alpha \in [a,b]$.
If we replace this set with $(a,b)$ ,then we can't make the claim that $\alpha \in (a,b)$,because the set is not closed.For example $1/(n+1)$ is a sequence in $(0,1)$ but it has no subsequence converging to a point in $(0,1)$.